# Highlight an entire UICollectionView section in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, border, cell, highlight

This collection has many items within many sections.  I am trying to  place a border around each section and further highlight it.

**Trail 1:**
Using headers and footers I can draw lines (header has top,left,right; footer has left,right,bottom) which look like frame ends.  But I can't get them to highlight on item select.

(I don't want to make this too complex by listing my code. I think there are tutorials to create collection *headers and footers*. But in summary: I created a *UICollectionReuseableView* class for each, *registered* them and applied a *referenceSize* for each of them.)

**Trial2:**
I can highlight each item, in that section (using a color with alpha overlay), when any item is selected.

(Again in summary: I used a *for loop* within the *didSelectItemAt* method.)

If each section was always one row of items, then I could use the item height, but thats not always the case - especially if rotated.

**How can I place a border around each section then highlight on item selection?**

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly (and I might not be) what you are asking for seems counter intuitive. What is a user supposed to think when see the entire section (not each individual item) selected? It seems to go against Apple's HIG which stresses the need for a uniform implementation of visual cues across apps. Why don't you believe that simply highlighting all the items in a section is the way to go?

Comment: @Magnas I want the user to select a group (section) ie. a style.  Each section has many items.  Highlighting all items in the section may be the only way it seems...